# ¿Cómo meter el script dentro de una clase?

Tags: javascript

Vale, una vez metido dentro de la `class` el `script` sin que haya ningún tipo de error, cuando intento ejecutar el programa en localhost, me da como resultado que las funciones no están declaradas:

```
class formLOGOSTariff{

   initL(){
     
      var temCard    = document.querySelector("#temp-card").innerHTML;
      var temPower   = document.querySelector("#temp-power").innerHTML;
      var temEnergy  = document.querySelector("#temp-energy").innerHTML;

      var contentForm   = document.querySelector("#content-form");

      let card = document.createElement("div");
         card.innerHTML = temCard
         contentForm.appendChild(card);

      let power = document.createElement("div");
       power.innerHTML = temPower;

      let energy = document.createElement("div");
       energy.innerHTML = temEnergy;

         card.querySelector(".container-power").appendChild(power);
         card.querySelector(".container-energy").appendChild(energy);
   }

   addPower(el)   {
      var temPower   = document.querySelector("#temp-power").innerHTML;

      let power = document.createElement("div");
      power.innerHTML = temPower;
      el.querySelector(".container-power").appendChild(power);
      return power;

   }
//       BTN ADD BUTTON V_ENERGY
   addEnergy(el)   {
      var temEnergy  =  document.querySelector('#temp-energy').innerHTML;

      let energy = document.createElement('div');
      energy.innerHTML = temEnergy;
      el.querySelector('.container-energy').appendChild(energy);
      return energy;
   }

   addFrm() {
      var tmp = document.querySelector('#temp-card').innerHTML;
    
      var cont = document.querySelector('#content-form')
      let frm = document.createElement('div');


      frm.innerHTML = tmp;
      cont.appendChild(frm);
      formLOGOSTariff.addPower(frm);
      formLOGOSTariff.addEnergy(frm);
      return frm;
   }

   sndFrm()   {
      var jotason = [];
      document.body.querySelectorAll(".templatecARD").forEach(form=>{

            let obj = {
               title : form.querySelector(".name_tarif").value
            };

            let power = {};
            form.querySelectorAll("input[name=t_power]").forEach((inpt, index)=>{
               var ob = power[index]||{};
               ob.type=inpt.value;
               power[index]=ob;
            });

            form.querySelectorAll("input[name=v_power]").forEach((inpt, index)=>{
               var ob = power[index]||{};
               ob.value=inpt.value;
               power[index]=ob;
            });

            let energy = {};
            form.querySelectorAll("input[name=t_energy]").forEach((inpt, index)=>{
               var oj = energy[index]||{};
               oj.type=inpt.value;
               energy[index]=oj;
            });

            form.querySelectorAll("input[name=v_energy]").forEach((inpt, index)=>{
               var oj = energy[index]||{};
               oj.value=inpt.value;
               energy[index]=oj;
            });

            obj.power = power;
            obj.energy = energy;
            jotason.push(obj);

      })
      var jsoned = JSON.stringify(jotason,undefined, 2);
      document.getElementById('txtare').value=jsoned;
   }

   sndTo(){
      document.querySelector('#content-form').innerHTML='';
      let pJsn = document.getElementById('txtare').value;

      var dat  = JSON.parse(pJsn);
      for(let n in dat){
         (form=>{

            let formDv = formLOGOSTariff.addFrm();
            formDv.querySelector(".container-power").innerHTML='vacio';

               for(let n1  in form.power){
                  (pow=>{
                     let power = formLOGOSTariff.addPower(formDv);
                     
                     power.querySelector("[name=t_power]").value=pow.type;
                     power.querySelector("[name=v_power]").value=pow.value;
                  })(form.power[n1])
               }

            formDv.querySelector(".container-energy").innerHTML='vacio';

               for(let n2 in form.energy){
                  (eng=>{
                     let energy = formLOGOSTariff.addEnergy(formDv);

                     energy.querySelector("[name=t_energy]").value=eng.type;
                     energy.querySelector("[name=v_energy]").value=eng.value;
                  })(form.energy[n2])
               }

            formDv.querySelector(".name_tarif").value=form.title;
           
         })(dat[n])
      }
   }
}



window.addEventListener("load",()=>{
   var nomVre = new formLOGOSTariff();
   nomVre.initL();


});
```

No entiendo el por qué no se declara, he intentado poner debajo de `nomVre.initL()` las funciones con la misma estructura:

`nomVre.addForm()` por ejemplo, y me da el mismo resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Cómo puedo solucionarlo?

**[EDIT]**

Cuando pongo por ejemplo: `nomVre.addPower(el);` el error que me sale es que `el` no está definido, ponga `el` o no.
Igualmente, pongo todas y cada una de las funciones a declarar, y sale el mismo error de siempre, no se declaran.

¿Cómo podría definir el `el` de dentro de la función addPower(el)?

Answer (score 1):

No sé lo que hace tu código, ni el objetivo de meterlo en una clase, pero mete no puedes hacer llamadas a funciones, ni crear funciones así sin más.

Si quieres que el `window.addEventListener` se ejecute nada más construir la clase, mételo dentro de un constructor.

Si quieres definir los métodos de la clase, elimina la palabra `function` de los métodos.

Si quieres que tu clase tenga propiedades, tendrás que definirlas (aunque no pareces usar ninguna).

```js
class nombreClase {
    propiedadEjemplo = 'Por si te interesa, una propiedad para tu clase';

    constructor() {
        window.addEventListener("load", () => { ... });
    }

    addPower(el) { ... }
    addEnergy(el) { ... }
    addFrm() { ... }
    reReload() { ... }
    sndFrm() { ... }
    sndTo() { ... }
}
```

Luego podrás usarlo como clase

```js
const miInstancia = new nombreClase();

miInstancia.addFrm();
miInstancia.reReload();
```